# How do i serve up a single page application from a sub-directory using nginx?

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to serve up a Angular application from a child path that is unique for the application. I've modified the app to use a base href of `fish`, and i can serve the root page and its assets correctly.

I am unable to reload the page on a child route. I get a 404.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$request_uri --- $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;


    upstream docker-backend-stream {
      server fish-api:80;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      autoindex off;

      location / {
            rewrite ^ http://www.google.com redirect;
      }

      location /fish {
        alias /app;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }

      location /fish/api {
            proxy_pass http://docker-backend-stream;
            auth_basic          off;
            client_max_body_size  0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Why is a GET request to http://localhost:80/fish/foo not being served index.html? It receives a 404 Not Found.**

Logs:

```
as-web_1       | 2017/12/01 18:16:14 [error] 8#8: *2 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.24.0.1, server: , request: "GET /fish/foo HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
as-web_1       | /fish/foo --- 172.24.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2017:18:16:14 +0000] "GET /fish/foo HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

As you can see above - the location directive isnt being matched, so nginx is looking for assets in the default root location of /etc/nginx/html.

Comment: The last element of the `try_files` statement should be a URI or a response code. Use `/fish/index.html` as that is the correct URI. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: @RichardSmith Even with /app/index.html set its looking in the global root. i think this is related to https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that there's a historical nginx bug that prevent both root and alias from properly taking hold on a location directive.

http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97

My work around uses a conditional check followed by a regex & rewrite:

```
  location /fish {
    alias /app;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^[^.]*$ /fish/index.html last;
    }
  }
```

Note: this could definitely be improved to check for file extensions